# how come php curl is using proxy

Tags: php, apache, curl, proxy, centos

I am stuck with this problem.

I have a cakephp application on Apache server.
this feature is using curl to fetch some data like below.

```
       $curl = curl_init($uri);
        curl_setopt_array(
            $curl,
            [
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => $headers,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            ]
        );

        ob_start();
        $apiContent = curl_exec($curl);

        // error check
        $curlErrorNo = curl_errno($curl);
        $curlErrorMsg = curl_error($curl);
```

the problem is the curl is using proxy even I unset the env https_proxy variables.
I debugged curl error message it is like this.

```
 About to connect() to proxy some-proxy port 9502 (#3)
   Trying 100.66.XXX.X...
 Connected to some-proxy (100.66.XXX.X) port 9502 (#3)
 Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to stg-platform.it.com:443
> CONNECT stg-xlatform.it.com:443 HTTP/1.1
```

which made curl request unsuccesful because api does NOT allow proxy.

I can bypass by set CURL_NOPROXY to curl options. But that is not the issue.

I need to know why curl is using proxy eventhough there seems to be no proxy settings at all.
Or Do I miss something here?

Your help will be really appreciated.
thanks in advance.